# Improve the quality of the google account image after login using google account in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-account

When I get the image of the login user using his google account the quality of the image that i get it from his google account has bad quality.

so How can improve the quality of the image that i get it from user google account ?

**I get the image of the user login using google account like this :**

```
 final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
            await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

        final token = googleSignInAuthentication;
// her i use this statement to take the google account image :  
              userImageUrl = googleSignInAccount.photoUrl
```

Answer (score 6):

Try the below code

```
userImageUrl = googleSignInAccount.photoUrl.replaceAll("s96-c", "s192-c");
```

Comment: Perfect for me!

Comment: There is no "s96-c" (or any size) in the photoUrl as of Nov 25, 2023.